# How to add timer parameter to executing code on github from AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have created a python script that moves the latest snapshot from one region to another. The script uses credentials locally on my machine to get the EC2 instance IDs to move, not sure if this will work for the below.

code:

```
import boto3

SOURCE_REGION = 'us-east-2'
DESTINATION_REGION = 'us-east-1'

# Connect to EC2 in Source region
source_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=SOURCE_REGION)

# Get a list of all snapshots, then sort them
snapshots = source_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])
snapshots_sorted = sorted([(s['SnapshotId'], s['StartTime']) for s in snapshots['Snapshots']], key=lambda k: k[1])
latest_snapshot = snapshots_sorted[-1][0]

print ('Latest Snapshot ID is ' + latest_snapshot)

# Connect to EC2 in Destination region
destination_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=DESTINATION_REGION)

# Copy the snapshot
response = destination_client.copy_snapshot(
    SourceSnapshotId=latest_snapshot,
    SourceRegion=SOURCE_REGION,
    Description='This is my copied snapshot'
    )

print ('Copied Snapshot ID is ' + response['SnapshotId'])
```

I found this link that says I can run python code in github from AWS using system manager (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/integration-remote-scripts.html#integration-github-python). Look for the title 'Run Python Scripts from GitHub
'.

In the guide there is the following command to execute code in github:

```
{"owner":"owner_name", "repository": "repository_name", "path": "path_to_scripts_or_directory", "tokenInfo":"{{ssm-secure:SecureString_parameter_name}}" }
```

Is there anyway I can add a timer into the above code so that my python script runs as per the timer?

Open to all suggestions to run python script remotely.

Thank you in advance.

edit:

could I feed in API keys through my code to avoid configuring credentials elsewhere?

**Edit2:**

Trying to put code into lambda function. Compressed `AWS_Backup.py` into `AWS_Backup.py.zip`. The handler info is changed too `AWS_Backup.handler` within AWS.

Code update:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    SOURCE_REGION = 'us-east-2'
    DESTINATION_REGION = 'us-east-1'

    # Connect to EC2 in Source region
    source_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=SOURCE_REGION)

    # Get a list of all snapshots, then sort them
    snapshots = source_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])
    snapshots_sorted = sorted([(s['SnapshotId'], s['StartTime']) for s in snapshots['Snapshots']], key=lambda k: k[1])
    latest_snapshot = snapshots_sorted[-1][0]

    print ('Latest Snapshot ID is ' + latest_snapshot)

    # Connect to EC2 in Destination region
    destination_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=DESTINATION_REGION)

    # Copy the snapshot
    response = destination_client.copy_snapshot(
        SourceSnapshotId=latest_snapshot,
        SourceRegion=SOURCE_REGION,
        Description='This is my copied snapshot'
        )

    print ('Copied Snapshot ID is ' + response['SnapshotId'])
```

error:  `"errorMessage": "Handler 'handler' missing on module 'AWS_Backup'"`

**Solution:**

```
change the lambda handler in AWS console from 'AWS_Backup.handler' to AWS_Backup.lambda_handler. Plus some role permissions were added to give me more access to IAM role.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is cool i did not know you could use SSM to execute code from github directly.

If you weren't married to a pure SSM solution you could incorporate lambda

**Two options.**

- Use Lambda and CloudWatch Events.  Put your code in Lambda, and use
  Cloud Watch Events to trigger the Lambda function.
- Use Lambda and CloudWatch Events to call SSM at the pre-determine interval. Essentially a shim that does the remote call.

Comment: I am trying the Lambda route but keep getting error:  ` "errorMessage": "Handler 'handler' missing on module 'AWS_Backup'"`. See edit for code update